# C++ automatic pre-processor code generation

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I have a snippet that looks like

```
std::string z_A_file("z_A.txt");
z_A_file = inputs_folder + z_A_file.c_str();
Eigen::Matrix<PRECISION, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> z_A_ = readArbitraryMatrix<PRECISION>(z_A_file.c_str());
Eigen::VectorXf z_A = z_A_;
//
std::string z_B_file("z_B.txt");
z_B_file = inputs_folder + z_B_file.c_str();
Eigen::Matrix<PRECISION, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> z_B_ = readArbitraryMatrix<PRECISION>(z_B_file.c_str());
Eigen::VectorXf z_B = z_B_;
```

Could I have a PRE-PROCESSOR function such that I just write

```
read_vector(A);
read_vector(B);
```

instead of repeating the same code ?

Comment: Somehow *Inception* comes to mind. And you could, but what use would that be? Create a collection of vectors, create a naming scheme that fits the files, map over it. Bonus points for a lambda.

Comment: If you have five or more such snippets, it might be worth the trouble. For just two, using a pre-processor is not worth losing the visibility of the code.

Comment: I have around 100 such snippets :-) so re-writing them may introduce bugs.

Comment: They are not as simple as A, B but the filenames are rather ad-hoc and complicated for each case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could I have a PRE-PROCESSOR function such that I just write

This file:

```
#define read_vector(x) \
std::string z_##x##_file("z_"#x".txt");\
z_##x##_file = input_folder + z_##x##_file.cstr();\
Eigen::Matrix<PRECISION, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> z_##x##_ = readArbitraryMatrix<PRECISION>(z_##x##_file.cstr());\
Eigen::VectorXf z_##x = z_##x##_;

read_vector(A);
read_vector(B);
```

After preprocessing:
`g++ -E main.cpp -o main.pp`

Became at:

```
# 1 "main.cpp"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "main.cpp"

std::string z_A_file("z_""A"".txt");z_A_file = input_folder + z_A_file.cstr();Eigen::Matrix<PRECISION, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> z_A_ = readArbitraryMatrix<PRECISION>(z_A_file.cstr());Eigen::VectorXf z_A = z_A_;;
std::string z_B_file("z_""B"".txt");z_B_file = input_folder + z_B_file.cstr();Eigen::Matrix<PRECISION, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> z_B_ = readArbitraryMatrix<PRECISION>(z_B_file.cstr());Eigen::VectorXf z_B = z_B_;;
```

Is this what you expect?

Comment: It's better to have an ugly macro than to have the same code-paragraph repeated 100 times; the latter is prone to inconsistency when people update the code (as they will sometimes forget to update all 100 instances, or mess up one or more of the 100 tedious edits that are necessary every time the formula changes)

Comment: While I think that @JeremyFriesner is totally right, this macro is *really* bad style: It inserts variable declarations, the following uses of those variables will appear to be completely magic. Of course, that's not an argument not to use it if it provides enough benefits, but those benefits must be really large to warrant such a counterintuitive macro. And it pretty much forces the macro to be used only within 50 lines of its definition. Best try to redefine the macro in such a way that it behaves like a function.